# Acces values inside a Future[Option[T]]

Tags: scala

I have a class

```
case class SomeClass(name: String, number: Long)
```

And I save it in the database. When I want to recover it from the database I get is as

`Future[Option[SomeClass]]`

How can I access the parameters from inside this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any more context, and if you don't want to wait on the future, you can just map it:

```
responseFromDatabase.map(_.map(_.name))
```

to have `Future[Option[String]]` that may contain the name.

If you really want to get the value, you can also

```
Await.result(responseFromDatabase).map(_.name).get
```

(or getOrElse with a default Name or something).

Can you provide more context?

Comment: I actually fixed using the result value and:
`future.map(_.asJson)`